# Shipping Labels not received for round trip courier service for UK Visa using VFS Global

Tags: visas, uk

I purchased the round-trip courier service through VFS Global. In the instructions, it states that you will receive in a separate email the shipping labels for this courier service. I receive Registration Details and Transaction Details only. No Shipping labels. I have called VFS Global in NY,NY and no human being access to ask questions, just an insane phone tree that does not answer my questions on how to get shipping labels that were never sent. I have called the British Consul in Atlanta and she could not answer my questions then transferred me to the same phone tree message that I receive through the British Consulate. I have sent emails to customercare@vfsglobal.com, info.vfsnewyork@vfsglobal.com, NYscanhub.escalate@vfsglobal.com, DLUKVInewyorksensitive@fco.gov.uk and I have received no response from anyone.

Frustrated. I do not know what to do. Please help me!!

Answer (score 3):

I just returned from UPS. I was led to believe that you have to use VFS Global to ship the visa documents. That is not necessary. Go to UPS yourself. Their representatives know what they are doing and will easily help you.

**DO NOT USE VFS GLOBAL.**

Go to UPS directly to get your shipping labels- the submission shipping label and also the return shipping label. UPS will mail your visa documents for better cost too.

When attempting to file a complaint to VFS Global for their lack of customer service, I found this notification on their website (yet they did not have a system within their website to make you aware of this glitz and they have not disabled this service option and they are still taking your money for their services!):

Issues with our Courier Services
Attention Customers who have purchased courier service and did not receive the shipping labels: 
We are experiencing technical issues and are working on resolving this as soon as possible,
We apologize for the inconvenience and request your patience as VFS works to resolve this issue.

Courier Services will be disabled for the time being

Customers who are interested in purchasing our courier services:  due to current technical issues on our website, we have disabled purchase of courier service. We are working to have the service back up and available to you as soon as possible. If you need to ship your application and documents, please visit your local UPS store and purchase the shipping labels directly through UPS.

Thank you for your patience at this time.